# In DB2, how can I declare a variable to use in multiple declared global temporary tables within the function..?

Tags: db2, db2-400

In DB2 for i v7r3m0, how can I declare a variable to use in multiple declared global temporary tables which follow within the same function..?

Below is a sample of my code. The full version has multiple DGTTs which do complex calculations and are then joined at the end. I would like to define the variable `FIRSTDAY` as shown, but this causes the following error:

```
SQL Error [42618]: [SQL0312] Variable FIRSTDAY not defined or not usable.
```

This seems like a context issue; the variable can't be seen in the context of the DGTT definition. If this were an independent SQL script, I could use `DECLARE VARIABLE` and it would work. Also, I could certainly duplicate the equation for `FIRSTDAY` multiple times, but I'd rather not do that.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_CERTOB.CertoNewPackageSheetsF1 ()
    RETURNS TABLE(  DAACCT  CHAR(5), 
                    DAIDAT  NUMERIC(8), 
                    DAINV   NUMERIC(15), 
                    QTY     NUMERIC(5)
                 )
    LANGUAGE SQL
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    NO EXTERNAL ACTION
BEGIN

    DECLARE FIRSTDAY NUMERIC(8) DEFAULT 0 ;
    SET     FIRSTDAY = (YEAR(CURDATE() - 4 MONTHS) * 10000) + (MONTH(CURDATE() - 4 MONTHS) * 100) ;

    DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.NPS_DATA0 -- CREATE INITIAL MAIN DATA SET
        AS  (   SELECT  DAACCT          AS DAACCT,
                        DAIDAT          AS DAIDAT,
                        DAINV#          AS DAINV,
                        DAQTY           AS QTY
                FROM    F_CERTOB.DAILYT
                WHERE   DAIDAT = FIRSTDAY
--                WHERE   DAIDAT = 20190501 -- THIS WORKS
            )   WITH DATA WITH REPLACE ;

-- DGTT 2 also uses FIRSTDAY

-- DGTT 3 also uses FIRSTDAY

RETURN SELECT * FROM SESSION.NPS_DATA0 ;

END @

SELECT * FROM TABLE(F_CERTOB.CertoNewPackageSheetsF1()) @

DROP FUNCTION   F_CERTOB.CertoNewPackageSheetsF1() @
DROP TABLE      SESSION.NPS_DATA0 @
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems, that it's not allowed to use variables in DDL statements.
Try to split the table declaration and data insertion steps like below:

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.NPS_DATA0 -- CREATE INITIAL MAIN DATA SET
    AS  (   SELECT  DAACCT          AS DAACCT,
                    DAIDAT          AS DAIDAT,
                    DAINV#          AS DAINV,
                    DAQTY           AS QTY
            FROM    F_CERTOB.DAILYT
--          WHERE   DAIDAT = FIRSTDAY
            WHERE   DAIDAT = 20190501 -- THIS WORKS
        )   WITH NO DATA WITH REPLACE ;

INSERT INTO SESSION.NPS_DATA0
SELECT  DAACCT          AS DAACCT,
        DAIDAT          AS DAIDAT,
        DAINV#          AS DAINV,
        DAQTY           AS QTY
FROM    F_CERTOB.DAILYT
WHERE   DAIDAT = FIRSTDAY;
```

Comment: Ah! Perfect, that seems to be working. Thanks for the tip. Again. =-)  I trimmed that down even a bit. For the DGTT I didn't even use the `SELECT` statement, just straight column definitions. Works fine and less to read that way.